# Cross-platform way to set environment variables *with spaces* in npm scripts

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables, npm-scripts

I am developing a serverless NodeJS app and need to test it in offline mode.  I have an `npm` script in a `package.json` file that looks like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "cross-env AUTHORIZER='{\\\"claims\\\":{\\\"permissions\\\":\\\"[view:accounts manage:accounts]\\\",\\\"sub\\\":\\\"auth0|5cfe0adce3c4c50ea072ea9f\\\"}}' AWS_PROFILE=elit_nonprd serverless offline start -s dev --noAuth",
...
```

Note that there two permissions that need to be **separated by a space**.  Running `npm run serve` on Windows gives the following error:

```
> @mypackage@1.0.0 serve C:\path
> cross-env AUTHORIZER='{\"claims\":{\"permissions\":\"[view:accounts manage:accounts]\",\"sub\":\"auth0|5cfe0adce3c4c50ea072ea9f\"}}' AWS_PROFILE=elit_nonprd serverless offline start -s dev --noAuth

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn manage:accounts]","sub":"auth0|5cfe0adce3c4c50ea072ea9f"}} ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\path\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\path\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\path\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\path\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn manage:accounts]","sub":"auth0|5cfe0adce3c4c50ea072ea9f"}}',
  path: 'manage:accounts]","sub":"auth0|5cfe0adce3c4c50ea072ea9f"}}',
  spawnargs: [
    'AWS_PROFILE=elit_nonprd',
    'serverless',
    'offline',
    'start',
    '-s',
    'dev',
    '--noAuth'
  ]
}
```

This also happens if I replace `cross-env` with `cross-env-shell`, although the stack-trace is not shown.

Is there a common cross-platform way to set environment variables when the values contain spaces?

**Update**: the outcome I am hoping for is to set `AUTHORIZER` to the following value (thanks to @RobC for requesting clarification):

```
{
  "claims":
  {
    "permissions": "[view:accounts manage:accounts]",
    "sub": "auth0|5cfe0adce3c4c50ea072ea9f"
  }
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219974/discussion-between-robc-and-ed-graham).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a puzzle this is to achieve cross-platform compatibility. After several failed attempts it does not seem possible to utilize a single syntax with `cross-env`:

Windows (`cmd`) works successfully with the `worksOnWin` example below, and *Nix (`sh`) works successfully with the `worksOnNix` example below.

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "worksOnWin": "cross-env AUTHORIZER={\\\"claims\\\":{\\\"permissions\\\":\\\"\"[view:accounts manage:accounts]\"\\\",\\\"sub\\\":\\\"auth0|5cfe0adce3c4c50ea072ea9f\\\"}} AWS_PROFILE=elit_nonprd serverless offline start -s dev --noAuth",
    "worksOnNix": "cross-env AUTHORIZER=\"{\\\"claims\\\":{\\\"permissions\\\":\\\"[view:accounts manage:accounts]\\\",\\\"sub\\\":\\\"auth0|5cfe0adce3c4c50ea072ea9f\\\"}}\" AWS_PROFILE=elit_nonprd serverless offline start -s dev --noAuth",
  }
}
```

#### Solution

To address your requirement for a single syntax cross-platform I would consider a different approach by utilizing a *node.js* script instead.

1. Save this `serve.js` script (below) in the root of your project directory, i.e. save it at the same level where *package.json* resides.

   **serve.js**

   ```js
   const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

   const processEnv = process.env;

   processEnv.AUTHORIZER = '{"claims":{"permissions":"[view:accounts manage:accounts]","sub":"auth0|5cfe0adce3c4c50ea072ea9f"}}';
   processEnv.AWS_PROFILE = 'elit_nonprd';

   spawn('serverless', ['offline', 'start', '-s', 'dev', '--noAuth'], {
     env: processEnv,
     stdio: 'inherit',
     shell: true
   });
   ```
2. In the `scripts` section of your *package.json* redefine your `serve` script as follows:

   **package.json**

   ```
   {
     ...
     "scripts": {
       "serve": "node serve"
     }
     ...
   }
   ```
3. Run the following command:

   ```
   npm run serve
   ```

#### Explanation

The following explains what's happening in *serve.js*:

- Firstly we require the [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module's [`spawn()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) method.
- The part that reads;

  ```js
  const processEnv = process.env;

  processEnv.AUTHORIZER = '{"claims":{"permissions":"[view:accounts manage:accounts]","sub":"auth0|5cfe0adce3c4c50ea072ea9f"}}';
  processEnv.AWS_PROFILE = 'elit_nonprd';
  ```

  obtains the existing environment variables, using [`process.env`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env), and assigns them to the `processEnv` variable.

  Subsequently, we augment the `processEnv` object with the `AUTHORIZER` and `AWS_PROFILE` properties and their necessary values. This essentially defines the two new Environment variables.
- Finally we *"shell out"* the `serverless offline start -s dev --noAuth` command via `child_process.spawn()`.

  - The `{ env: processEnv }` part sets `child_process.spawn`'s [`env`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) option to the `processEnv` object, i.e. it sets the environment variables for the child process.
  - The [`stdio`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_stdio) option configures the pipes for stdin, stdout, stderr in the child process. This ensures you get any logging in the console.
  - The `shell` option is set to `true`.

<sub>**Note:** The `cross-env` package becomes redundant using this solution.</sub>

Comment: Fabulous answer and explanation, @RobC - thank you so much!  I have also raised a bug for this issue against `cross-env` [here](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env/issues/248) as I believe the package was intended to be able to handle values with spaces.